# array output - order in the index structure

Tags: php, algorithm, while-loop

I have this code

```
$nArr = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');

$counter = 3;
while ($counter > 0) {
    $chunkedValues[$counter][0] = 1;
    for ($j = 0 ; $j < $counter ; $j++) {
        $chunkedValues[$counter][$j + 1] = $nArr[$j];
    }
    $nArr = array_slice($nArr, $counter--);
}
var_dump($chunkedValues);
```

that outputs:

```
array
  3 => 
    array
      0 => int 1
      1 => string 'A' (length=1)
      2 => string 'B' (length=1)
      3 => string 'C' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => int 1
      1 => string 'D' (length=1)
      2 => string 'E' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => int 1
      1 => string 'F' (length=1)
```

**But i need this index structure:**

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => int 1
      1 => string 'A' (length=1)
      2 => string 'B' (length=1)
      3 => string 'C' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array
      1 => int 1
      2 => string 'D' (length=1)
      3 => string 'E' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array
      2 => int 1
      3 => string 'F' (length=1)
```

I want to avoid loops with `ceil`.

Any idea? thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$nArr = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');

$chunkedValues = array();
$gCounter = 0;
for ($counter = 3, $start = 0; $counter > 0; $counter--, $start++) {
    $arr = array($start => 1);
    for ($j = 0; $j < $counter; $j++) $arr[]= $nArr[$gCounter++];
    $chunkedValues []= $arr;
}

var_dump($chunkedValues);
```

OR if you don't care about order of the elements:

```
$nArr = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');

$chunkedValues = array();
$gCounter = 0;
for ($counter = 3, $start = 0; $counter > 0; $counter--, $start++) {
    $arr = array_combine(
        range($start+1, $counter)
        array_slice($nArr, $gCounter, $gCounter += $counter);
    );
    $arr[$start] = 1;
    $chunkedValues []= $arr;
}

var_dump($chunkedValues);
```

Comment: nop, [0][0] should be 1, [1][1] should be 1, [2][2] should be 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just splitting up an array?

It looks like you might be able to just use:

```
$nArr = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$chunked = array_chunk($nArr , 3);
var_dump($chunked);
```